# Facebook Like Box breaking div in IE 8. Why?

Tags: css, facebook-like

I have a Facebook Like Box added to my site and it's loading properly on Firefox, Google Chrome, Opera and Safari, but IE 8 is "breaking my div" (check the bottom border and you'll be able to see what I'm talking about). Also, the color background won't show.

Live here: http://www.baskra.com/novo

*The screenshot below shows Google Chrome on the left and IE 8 on the right.*

[image]

HTML:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fagenciabaskra&amp;width&amp;height=258&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;header=false&amp;stream=false&amp;show_border=false&amp;appId=379823488795975" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:258px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

CSS:

```
#curtir {
    width:300px; 
    height:235px; 
    background: #F5F5F5;
    border: 1px solid #3b5997; 
    margin-left:2px;
    margin-top:2px;
    display:none; 
    position:absolute;
    z-index:9999;
    }
```

What do you think would be the best way to fix this? I don't want to increase my div's height. Any thoughts will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT:** just tried to see what happens with Safari for Windows. When I click on the logo, it shows me an empty div (with background and border, but no Like Box inside of it). What might cause this?

Comment: I checked your website on IE 8 (switching to IE8 from developer tools) but it is appearing fine with border at bottom.

Comment: That's weird, ravk, I'm still facing the same problem and I haven't found a solution yet. What about Safari for Windows? It keeps showing an empty `div` for me.